# jquery selector with variable does not find element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this line of code

`$("#ir-area-name").html(list);`

That works just fine, but I need to move this into a function that can be called for any id, and every answer I have seen says I can run it like this:

`$("#"+variable_name).html(list);`

where `variable_name` is a string containing the id. But, this isn't working for me, it doesnt find any element and no error message is printed. When printing the contents of the selector to console they both print the value `[object Object]`. However, when running it with the variable the element dissapears from screen (as it apparently didn't find the element so it never ran `html()`). For testing purposes I tried it like this as well:

`$("#"+"ir-area-name").html(list);`

But this still didn't find the element. So the question is how can I use a variable in a jquery selector (using jquery 1.7.1, testing on firefox).

Comment: why are you using this very old jquery version? And it should work with `$("#"+variable_name)` maybe variable_name is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use string concatenation.

```
$("#" + ir-area-name).html(list)
```

Or using ES6 string substitution syntax [(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
$(`#${ir-area-name}`).html(list)
```

If the element is found, the html of the element will be replaced with the contents of `list`.

Comment: `${"#" + variable_name)` ?

Comment: Edited. Used the wrong example. Also added a link to the docs